# Collapse row layout to column at smaller widths without losing the margin-top for the previous element

Tags: html, css, sass

### Targets

I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. When the screen is enough wide, the `.firstItem` (red) and `.lastItem` (blue) elements, **whose widths are unknown in advance**, are on left and right part of parent `.layout` respectively.

[image]

2. When the screen becomes narrower and horizontal spacing between items reduced to `$minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems`, the layout collapses to column, but the `.firstItem` is still justified to left and `.lastItem` to right:

[image]

3. The vertical space between items `$verticalSpaceBetweenItems` must not affect the layout in the single row configuration.
4. The below CSS rule for the yellow `.preceedingElement` block above `.firstItem` and `.lastItem` must work:

```css
.preceedingElement + .layout {
   margin-top: Npx;
}
```

### Basic MWE

```html
<div class="preceedingElement"></div>
<div class="layout">
  <div class="firstItem"></div>
  <div class="lastItem"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.preceedingElement{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FAD7A0;
}

@mixin TwoSpacedItemsComposition(
  $minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems: 0,
  $verticalSpaceBetweenItems: 0
) {
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  margin-top: -$verticalSpaceBetweenItems;
  margin-right: -$minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems;
  
  
  > *{
    margin-top: $verticalSpaceBetweenItems;
    margin-right: $minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems;
    
    &:last-child {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  }
}
  
.layout {
  @include TwoSpacedItemsComposition(
    $minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems: 12px,
    $verticalSpaceBetweenItems: 24px
  )
}

.firstItem {
  width: 200px;
  height: 34px;
  background: #EC7063;
}

.lastItem {
  width: 400px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #7FB3D5;
}
```

### Flex solution attempt

Below SASS mixin implements all targets except fourth:

```css
@mixin TwoSpacedItemsComposition(
  $minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems: 0,
  $verticalSpaceBetweenItems: 0
) {
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  margin-top: -$verticalSpaceBetweenItems;
  margin-right: -$minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems;
  
  
  > *{
    margin-top: $verticalSpaceBetweenItems;
    margin-right: $minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems;
    
    &:last-child {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

The interference is `margin-top: -$verticalSpaceBetweenItems;` for parent and `margin-top: $verticalSpaceBetweenItems;` for child.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dsx8oh5/1/)

### Grid solution attempt

The grid always renders 2 rows.

```
@mixin TwoSpacedItemsComposition(
  $minimalHorizontalSpaceBetweenItems: 0,
  $verticalSpaceBetweenItems: 0
) {

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, auto));
  grid-gap: $verticalSpaceBetweenItems $verticalSpaceBetweenItems;

  align-items: center;


  >* {

    &:first-child {
      justify-self: start;
    }

    &:last-child {
      justify-self: end;
    }
 }
```

Comment: 1. Your HTML should also be in the question. (I realize it's minimal but the question should contain all the code necessary to reproduce the issue.) 2. Your current explanation of what you're trying to do relys on the reader being able to see the image **and** be able to distinguish colors, which won't always be true. Referring to them as the top full width header, a left column, and a right column would be clearer for folks who can't see the image.

Comment: @BSMP, "Your HTML should also be in the question" - I added. But I can't use the StackOverlow fiddle because it does not support the css preprocessors (mixin functionality required in this question). "Your current explanation of what you're trying to do relys" - they are not columns in "container" meaning, "they" could the the input elements or buttons. I'll refer to them by CSS classes.

Comment: Using the Stack Overflow fiddle isn't a requirement, it's OK that you're not using it. As long as the code is in the question, that's good enough.

Comment: @BSMP, got it. I'll append the HTML code in my future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flexbox approach seems to work perfectly... Changing `margin-top: $verticalSpaceBetweenItems;` to `margin-bottom: $verticalSpaceBetweenItems;` should solve requirement #4, and your original flexbox code solved the first three already.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yx689sh4/

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using percentages for the widths for your two items?

Comment: Thank you for the answer trying. Please, write the comment instead of answer, if your message does not contain the solution. Also, the condition of this problem is *item's 
 widths are unknown in advance*, so the percentage could not be used for solution.